# Manipulate an image on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I have to load an image on a canvas object and after clicking some buttons or sliding some sliders, I need to change some pixels on this canvas. Thats my code so far:

```
function CanvasImage(element, src) {

    var width, height;
    var canvas = document.getElementById(element);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image;

    img.onload = function () {

        width = canvas.width = img.width;
        height = canvas.height = img.width;

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)
    };
    img.src = src;

    this.brightness = function (amount) {

        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var data = imgData.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {

            data[i] += amount;
            data[i + 1] += amount;
            data[i + 2] += amount
        }
        imgData.data = data;
        ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0)
    };

    this.transform = function (data) {

        ctx.save();
        this.brightness(data.brightness);
        ctx.restore()
    }

}
```

Thats I've just added the function to manipulate the brightness of the image. At the beginning, the image is loaded to the canvas element. That works fine for me. The function brightness is just adding the giving amount to the pixels. That also works. I think my problem is the transform function. I save the state of the canvas context and call my transform function. After this manipulation I restore the state. I would say, the context should look like the earlier loaded image.

My problem now is, that after changing a slider and returning it to the original state my image is still brighter or darker and doesn't have the original state of the image. Do you have any suggestions for me, please?

I appreciate every answer. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save` and `restore` only saves the state of the canvas not image data. State are things such as styles, translations, text alignment and so forth.

In order to get back original content you need to either redraw the source or store the data to be restored with another canvas element (ie. off-screen canvas), or store the data as an array (`getImageData()`).

Also worth to notice is that `putImageData` by-passes the canvas' state and changes pixels directly independently.

My recommendation would be to keep the source available one way or another and always redraw it to canvas before a new alteration takes place. For reset simply redraw source and skip alteration.

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/6xqFY/)**

```
this.brightness = function (amount) {

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)

    /// no change, just exit
    if (amount === 0) return;

    /// ... snipped        
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I redraw the image on the context after I have saved it. :D That works nice for me. Thanks! :D